# Mysql Trigger null result

Tags: mysql, triggers, null

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
use my_database;
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Comit $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Comit ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE ids INT;
    DECLARE leftChilds INT;
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM user;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    
    OPEN cur;
        ins_loop: LOOP
            FETCH cur INTO ids;
            IF done THEN
                LEAVE ins_loop;
            END IF;
            SET leftChilds = ( SELECT turnoverBalance FROM user WHERE proposer = ids AND side = 'left' LIMIT 1 );
            INSERT INTO log(`log`) VALUES ( leftChilds );

        END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;
    
END $$
```

When i call the procedure call Comit(); that return me this error :

> ## 1048 - Column 'log' cannot be null

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery is generating `NULL` values, probably because there is no match on the `proposer` condition.  Of course, your data could also have `NULL` values for `turnoverBalance` in `user` or rows with no `'left'` side.

In any case, why are you using a cursor for something that is easily done as a single query?  Something like this can replace all the logic:

```
INSERT INTO log(log)
    SELECT turoverBalance
    FROM user
    WHERE proposer IN (SELECT id FROM user) AND side = 'left')
    GROUP BY proposer;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, its are stored procedure, not a trigger.
Check what your set leftChilds query returns, it should return some value, run it individually.
You can Check in stored procedure
`If(leftChilds not NULL) 
insert into log('log') values (leftChilds)`